# Is there a name for the relation between a proposition and the proposition formed after applying the diamond modal operator?

Tags: terminology, modal-logic

I don't know if there is a name for it but, since a negative proposition is the *negation of* another proposition for e.g. the proposition that "it is not the case that it is sunny" is the *negation of* "it is sunny". Does that mean that the proposition "It is possible that it is sunny" stands to the proposition "It is sunny" in some sort of relationship, if so does it have a name?

Comment: Some authors occasionally call it "possibilification", see e.g. [von Wright, A New system of modal logic](https://filosofia.fi/sv/arkisto/new-system-modal-logic). But generally the word is used loosely for introducing possibility somehow somewhere.

Comment: This does not exactly answer your question, but adding a box or diamond to a proposition is sometimes described as giving it a *modal force*.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a relation? Well, diamond and square certainly are unitary operators that transform a proposition. Is it named and does the name have currency? That is, do they have a grammatical presence as nouns and verbs like 'negation' and 'to negate', what one would call a lexical definition, a description of current usage? I don't think so. In [logical modality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic)

> the modal formula ◊P can be read as "possibly P" while ◻P can be read as "necessarily P"

If you're looking for a parallel grammatical construction to "X is the *negation of* Y, then you seem to be out of luck. Of course, no one can stop your from coining language and persuading others to use it, so you might go with:

> For necessity, X is the *necessitation* of Y (since one speaks of the Necessitation Rule)

It's a little akward, but I think it's understandable. I guess like "~ negates a proposition" you might say "◻ necessitates a proposition".

> For possibility, X is the *possibilization* of Y

That's more awkward and there doesn't seem to be any use of the term at all even if it comports with being parallel gramatically. Could you say "◊ possibilizes a proposition"? Again, you could. There's actually an [entry for it in the urban dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=possibilize) which purports itself to be a catalog of [neologisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism). Google [Ngram viewer also shows a climb in usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=possibilize&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3). If you Google "possibilize a proposition", it returns at least [one paper that uses the language](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20012446).

The moral of the story here is that this would, as far as I can tell with my limited resources, be idiosyncratic, non-canonical language. As such, anyone using these constructions would be best off to initially use [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) and perhaps have an explicit mention of the effort to move such language into convention.

Comment: Thanks for your help JD! I found this book about propositions in the section logic https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-history-of-hellenistic-philosophy/73E597AACD9FF9CCE077C41A3E9548C7 which you might like to read